# If $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, $X$ is compact, and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and surjective, then $f$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms, open-map

I was given the following assertion:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, $X$ is compact, and $f:X\to Y$ is
>   continuous and surjective, then $f$ is open.

However, I believe that I have a counterexample:

Define $f:[0,3]\to[0,2]$ by

$$
x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x&0\leq x\leq1,\\
1&1<x<2,\\
x-1&2\leq x\leq3.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $[0,3]$ and $[0,2]$ are Hausdorff, $[0,3]$ is compact, and $f$ is continuous and surjective. However, $[0,3/2)$ is open in $[0,3]$ but $f([0,3/2))=[0,1]$ is not open in $[0,2]$.

Does this look correct? If so, then is there a similar theorem?

Comment: I think $[0,\frac32)$ is not open

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti, why not?

Comment: @Raptor Can you find an open ball around zero, that is entirely contained in $[0,\frac{3}{2})$?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, $B_{3/2}(0)=\{x\in[0,3]:|x|<3/2\}$ does it.

Comment: $[0,3/2)$ is open **in $X$**.  The counterexample is correct, and the assertion is wrong.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't understand how $[0,\frac{3}{2})$ is open in $[0,3]$? The subspace topology on $[0,3]$ says that $[0,\frac{3}{2})$ must be the intersection of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with $[0,3]$ in order to be an open set (in the ordinary topology), right? But then that's not true? Or is it?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, $[0,3/2)=(-3/2,3/2)\cap[0,3]$.

Comment: It is open in the relative topology which is what is being used here, we are looking at $X$ as it inherits its subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$. Since for example $(-1,3/2)\cap X= [0,3/2)$ this proves the set is  open ( in the subspace topology)

Comment: @Raptor Oh, I see. I get it. But then there is a very similar statement that is true, something like: "A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism". But then your function is not a bijection, so I see where the counterexample is coming from. Right, thank you for this question, and $+1$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, perhaps whoever told me this meant to say that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: @Raptor I think so, I really do, because the proof of that fact is a standard (and nice) topological exercise.

Comment: @RobertIsrael you are right! Damn, how fool I have been!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some more or less similar theorems:

1. If $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f\colon X\to Y$ is closed.
2. If $f$ is in addtion bijective then $f(U^C)=f(U)^C$ and thus $f$ is open
3. In functional analysis there is the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)). For continuous lineare operators the statement is true, there are open if and only if they are surjective.